Making an UncheckedAccount a signer in some conditions
We have an account like pub owner: UncheckedAccount<'info>,, and it's a required account because it is used to derive seeds for another account.
In certain circumstances, but not always, this account must sign:
if some_condition { 
            let owner = &ctx.accounts.owner;
            if !owner.is_signer {
                panic!("Owner must sign");
            }
}

Now on the front end, when sending a tx, this works fine if the sender is also the owner (since the sender always signs their tx). So for example, if we have a sender like:
  const provider = new AnchorProvider(program.provider.connection, userWallet, {});
  const userProgram = new Program(program.idl, program.programId, provider);

This will work fine:
await userProgram.provider.sendAndConfirm(new Transaction().add(this_ix));

However, if another sender wants to sign this tx, now we have a problem, because owner isn't actually a signer in the IDL. For example:
    await program.provider.sendAndConfirm(tx, [userWallet]);

will fail with unknown signer (userWallet's key). And likewise, attempting to partialSign will fail:
    tx.recentBlockhash = program.provider.connection.getLatestBlockhash();;
    tx.feePayer = program.provider.publicKey;
    tx.partialSign(usersWallet);

So what is the best solution for an account that is required, and is sometimes-but-not-always a signer?

There could be but I'm not aware of such functionality within Anchor.
I would probably use two separate instruction input accounts. One is the required non-signer UncheckedAccount<'info> and the other is Optional Signer account.
Then the program code (or the Anchor macro) must verify that when the Signer is provided the Signer and UncheckedAccount pubkeys match.
